# Laravel many to many relationships - retrieving models

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship

If we have something like this:

### user

- id
- name

### role

- id
- name

## shop

- id
- name

## role_user

- role_id
- user_id

## shop_user

- shop_id
- user_id

Quick: shop---shop_user---user---role_user---role

and we want all USER from SHOP 1 with ROLE admin. How can we do that?

all USER from SHOP 1:

```
$shop = Shop::find( $shopId );
$shop->users()->get();
```

Something like this would be nice:

```
$shop = Shop::find( $shopId );
$shop->users()->roles->()->where( 'name', 'Admin' )->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your relationships work as intended, this should get you the result you want:

```
$shop = Shop::with(['users' => function ($q) {
    $q->whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
        $q->where('name', 'Admin');
    });
}])->find($shopId);
```

It will select Shop with `id = $shopId` and it will attach all `users` to it, that have `role` where `roles.name = Admin`

You get the users like this `$users = $shop->users`

Answer (score -1):

Use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method:

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function($q) use($roleId) {
        $q->where('id', $roleId)
    })->whereHas('shops', function($q) use($shopId) {
        $q->where('id', $shopId)
    })->get();
```

Comment: This does not work $users = User::whereHas(  'roles', function ( $q ) use ( $roleId ) { $q->where( 'id', $roleId ); } )->get();
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous. This does work $users = User::whereHas(  'roles', function ( $q ) use ( $roleName ) { $q->where( 'name', $roleName ); } )->get();

Comment: @baker I forgot to change `roles` to `shops` in second `whereHas()`. Fixed now. Make sure you've defined `roles` and `shops` relationships correctly.

Comment: The downvote is not from me. But this does not work: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous.

Comment: @baker please post appropriate migrations and relationships. If devk's answer works for you this means `users` relationship works fine, but something's wrong with `shops` relationship or shops related migrations.

Comment: **User**: belongsToMany(Role::class) and belongsToMany(Shop::class) **Shop**: belongsToMany(User::class) **Role**: belongsToMany(User::class)